# In United States En-US like Norweigian encoding?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

While programming i have some problem with Encoding..

In United States En-US like Norweigian encoding ?

I want norweigian encoding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such encodings, or at most they are unofficial (and misleading) names for encodings. There is a [registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets) (by IANA) of character encodings, with preferred names and alias names.

“United States En-US” sounds like an attempt to give a “friendly” name to a locale. A locale does not imply a particular encoding.

My guess is that “Norwegian encoding” means either windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1 these days, but it could also be some old encoding.

Answer (score 0):

*Not a reliable answer*, but a reference source I would like to mention:

[Character Encoding Recommendation for Languages](http://scratchpad.wikia.com/wiki/Character_Encoding_Recommendation_for_Languages).
Please note that **ISO-8859-4** is mentioned for the northern scandinavic languages. I have no experience though. **Windows-1252** seems possible too, maybe missing some Norwegian sign though, and that is the same as in the United States: Windows extension of Latin-1.

In general it would be best if **UTF-8** is possible: full Unicode, for all languages.